# In Xunit tests for net461, how to enable /disable AppDomain in Windows /Linux when using dotnet test CLI

Tags: linux, msbuild, xunit, appdomain, dotnet-test

In CI server, I run tests in net4x for both windows and Linux and I want to enable/disable `Appdomain` based on OS.

In net4x, Xunit tests can be build in both windows and Linux

[Getting Started with xUnit.net Multi-targeting with non-Windows OSes](https://xunit.net/docs/getting-started/multi-target/non-windows)

by adding the package

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETFramework' ">
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

`dotnet test` can run Xunit tests  in Linux when  MONO is installed.

```
dotnet test --settings additionalargs.runsettings
```

The cli command `dotnet test` use [.runsettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN) to configure tests, but Xunit test configuration are not available.

Is there a way to enable then  disable  AppDomain in Windows/Linux respectively in dotnet test when running Xunit test project?

something like:

```
dotnet test --setting appDomain=denied??? # in linux, 
dotnet test --setting appDomain=required??? # in windows
```

Comment: .NET FW 4.x can work only on Windows. Are you targeting Mon or .NET Core?

Comment: Now, net4x can work in Linux with Mono Installed in Linux, see my [ref link](https://xunit.net/docs/getting-started/multi-target/non-windows), and I did in windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 using the command `dotnet test`